# How do I get a hexadecimal IntPtr with leading 0x0?

Tags: c#, hex, intptr

I am trying to programmatically get an IntPtr for sending messages and keys to outside programs. I can get the correct hexadecimal value for button handles.

```
Console.WriteLine(myIntPtr) //If I take the number here as, say, XXX
IntPtr manualIntPtr = (IntPtr)0x0XXX; //I type this in so I can confirm I need the 0x0 portion
SendMessage(manualIntPtr, 0x0F5, 0, IntPtr.Zero); //This successfully clicks a button with handle 0x0XXX
```

My issue is that my programmatically obtained IntPtr is not in the format "0x0XXX". If I do something like

```
myIntPtrString = "0x0" + Convert.ToString(myIntPtr);
myIntPtr = IntPtr(Convert.ToString(myIntPtrString)); // I'm brand new to C#, there's probably a better way to do this
```

then the 0x0 is lost and SendMessage() no longer works. Is there some way to get "0x0" saved inside of an IntPtr? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please, share the code which is used to obtain `IntPtr`

Comment: Why do you think you need the "0x" part? Why are you converting to string? Can't you just `SendMessage(btnHWND, 0x0F5, 0, myIntPtr);`?

Comment: To get the IntPtr, it's a little roundabout. ```tuneHWND = (IntPtr)decToHexa(Convert.ToInt32(auto.WinGetHandle("ApplicationName", null), 16));``` I had to go with AutoITX3 as it was more reliable in getting the correct handles.

Comment: Without the "0x0" portion in the manualIntPtr, the SendMessage() doesn't work. With it and with no other changes, SendMessage() clicks the button. And sorry about the confusion in the SendMessage() - I've corrected it (error caused by copying from code and making it more readable on here/missing a variable)

Comment: _Is there some way to get "0x0" saved inside of an IntPtr_ The "0x" notation is only there to tell the compiler that the number is hex and not dec. Once have created the variable, it no longer matters. `int a = 0x10;` is the same as `int a = 16;`.

Comment: Thanks Johnny - I feel pretty silly now - If i put it in as a decimal number I can click the button meaning no need for a "0x0". I had a fair amount of a struggle getting SendMessage() to work and landed on the conclusion that I HAD to have my IntPtr saved as a hex number (despite them all being in 1s and 0s). You've corrected my error in thinking.